# Issue with the Kusto pack function producing json with \u200b special character

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

Let's take the following query as an example to reproduce the issue:

```
datatable(Computer:string, TimeGenerated:datetime, data:dynamic)
[
    "comp1",  datetime(2019-02-07 16:31:15), dynamic([{"prop1": 2}, {"prop2": 0.8}, {"prop3": 12.204532}, {"prop4": 0}]),
    "comp2",  datetime(2019-02-07 16:31:15), dynamic([{"prop1": 2}, {"prop2": 0.8}]),
    "comp3",  datetime(2019-02-07 16:31:15), dynamic([{"prop2": 0.8}, {"prop3": 12.204532}, {"prop4": 0}]),
]
| mv-apply e = data on (summarize data = make_bag(e))
| extend o = pack(Computer, data)
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, o
```

If you look at the JSON produced by pack and try to validate it, you will see that there is an extra character that makes the json invalid.

[image]

You'll see that the validator shows:

[image]

The special character shown in the picture is \u200b.

Am I doing something wrong on the query or is it a potential bug and how to fix it please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the issue doesn't reproduce when copying the result of the query you provided as-is from the ADX public web interface, and validating it using https://jsonlint.com/. it may be a result of the client you're using and/or how you're copying the payload - you may want to clarify which one it is (is it a public web interface / a custom client application / etc.) and provide _full_ repro steps

Comment: You're right. In ADX public web interface I have valid JSON. The problem arise when you run query on log analytics from the azure portal. If you run the query from the portal and copy the json you will that the extra character really exists.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observations in my local environment when you are running the query in the log analytics workspace you are writing to create a bag twice in `mv-apply` and in `extend` due to this we are getting a special character `'.'` in output `'o'`. we removed the mv-apply and tested the query it doesn't show any error to us.

[image]

Here are our observations with `mv-apply` and without `mv-apply`.

1. With `mv-apply`

[image]

2. With out `mv-apply`
   [image]